# I detected memory issues with valgrid in the constructors. How do I solve this?

Tags: c++

Currently I'm learning about classes and constructors. I modified the following code. When I run the code with valgrid it gives the message that there are memory issues. I don't see where these come from.

```
#include <iostream>

class Container
{
...

public:
    // constructors
    Container() {
        length = 0;
        data = nullptr;
        print("default constructor");}

    Container(int len){
        int lenght = len;
        data = new double[lenght];
    }

    Container(std::initializer_list<double> il): Container(il.size())
    {
        std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), data);
    }

   

    // destructor

    // operators
    void print(const std::string& info) const
    {
        // print the address of this instance, the attributes `length` and
        // `data` and the `info` string
        std::cout << "  " << this << " " << length << " " << data << "  "
            << info << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int length;
    double* data;
};

int main()
{
    Container x = {1,2,3,4};
    std::cout << "x has address " << &x << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I got from valgrid:

```
Valgrind detected memory issues:
==21== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21== Command: ./temp_student_code
==21== 
x has address 0x1fff000ca0
==21== 
==21== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21==     in use at exit: 74,035 bytes in 10 blocks
==21==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 1 frees, 74,091 bytes allocated
==21== 
==21== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==21==    at 0x489F344: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:433)
==21==    by 0x109379: Container::Container(int) (student_code.cpp:20)
==21==    by 0x1093D8: Container::Container(std::initializer_list<double>) (student_code.cpp:23)
==21==    by 0x109285: main (student_code.cpp:49)
==21== 
==21== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==21==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21==    still reachable: 74,003 bytes in 9 blocks
==21==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I cannot figure out on my own where this goes wrong. Could I please get some advise on how to solve the memory issues?

Comment: You call `new` in your constructor, but never call `delete[]` anywhere (which should probably be in the destructor)

Comment: Where did your destructor go? There is a nice comment, but no code :). If you manually allocate memory on the heap `data = new double[lenght];`, you need to release it manually as well (via `delete` / `delete[]`)

Comment: It looks weird that the length information is not stored to the member variables in the constructor `Container(int len)`.

Comment: Yeah, if the compiler complains it doesn't know what `lenght` is, the solution is not to add a local variable with the same mis-spelling, but to fix the spelling. An IDE or editor with auto-completion will help avoid this sort of typo, as will just copying-and-pasting if you think two things _should_ be the same and the compiler disagrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing the needed destructor to free the memory you manually allocated via `new`.
2. You are saving the length in a local variable `int lenght = len;`, where you probably want to save it in the class member `length`.

I.e. a minimal example would be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Container
{
public:
    // constructors
    Container() = default() // no allocation!
    Container(int len) : length(len) {
        data = new double[len];
    }

    // destructor
    ~Container() {
      releaseMemory_();
    }

    // Copy ctor
    Container(const Container& other) : Container(other.length) {
      if (data != nullptr) { std::copy(data, data + length, other.data); }
    }

    // Move ctor
    Container(Container&& other) {
      std::swap(length, other.length);
      std::swap(data, other.data);
    }

    // Assignment operator
    Container& operator=(const Container& other) {
      releaseMemory_();

      this->length = other.length;
      if (other.data != nullptr) {
        this->data = new double[length];
        std::copy(this->data, this->data + length, other.data);
      }
    }

    // Other stuff ...

private:
    int length = 0;
    double* data = nullptr;

    void releaseMemory_() {
      if (data != nullptr) {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;
      }
    }
};
```

**EDIT** : Added copy ctor, move ctor & assignment operator for completeness. Not directly related to the memory leak in the example, but good practice :+1

Comment: Also don't forget to follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (Explicit copy constructor and assignment operator should be added to copy the contents of array instead of the pointer to the array)